# Should I release an UIImageView added to my view if I will detect touch on it later on?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sdk, uiimageview, release

I've learnt that if you create an object, you own it and need to release it when you're done with it. In this case I create an UIImageView and add it to my view like this:

```
myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
[myImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,100,100)];
[self.view addSubview:myImageView]; 
[myImageView release];
```

If I later on want to detect touch on myImageView like this in my touchEnded-method:

```
if([touch view] == myImageView){
    NSLog(@"TOUCHED!");
}
```

This works, but is this correct, since I now used myImageView after releasing it?
And how do I release myImageView from the self.view that I added it to earlier?

Comment: Is `myImageView` an instance var?

Comment: It is a IBOutlet UIImageView *myImageView, is that an ivar?

Comment: @molle: If it's declared inside your `@interface`, yes it is.

Comment: @BoltClock What @molle is describing is a property. It is not an instance variable; the two are mutually exclusive.

Comment: @kubi: I assumed it was an ivar because the OP code appears to be manipulating an ivar and not a property (no dot notation or accessor messages).

Comment: @mollle You should not be assigning to an IBOutlet. IBOutlets are set by Interface Builder and you should not change their values. Do you have it wired to something in IB? If not, then don't make it an IBOutlet. If so, then don't change what it points to.

Answer (score 1):

The cardinal rule of Cocoa memory management is that you should retain those things you care about, and release those things you do not care about. There are a very small number of exceptions to prevent retain loops (delegates and datasources are never retained), but this is the rule you should follow.

In this case, if you are storing the image in an ivar, I would continue to retain it, regardless of the fact that its superview will always retain it, and so you don't "have" to. But if the view is removed from its superview, you will wind up with a dangling pointer, and then you will crash, so I code defensively against that by retaining. If you used an accessor here (which you should), then this would be automatic and much safer.

Apple has grown more consistent about this in iOS, switching their recommendation about IBOutlets. On Mac, you do not retain your IBOutlets, but in iOS, Apple [explicitly instructs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmNibObjects.html) you to do so. This is similar to the situation you are discussing, and I agree with Apple's move towards a safer approach.

Comment: I've not seen that document before (possibly because I'm solely an iOS dev). That's going to be useful, +1

Comment: I think you should be a touch more specific concerning memory management in Objective C (as opposed to Cocoa...). The cardinal rule is that you are _responsible_ for things you _create_ (with alloc, new or copy. Or if you send it retain). In other words, you take ownership. The way you phrased it is too loose and will confuse the author of the question.

Comment: @6NSString, You're describing when retains are created (the three magic words), but this does not answer the poster's question of when you *should* retain. That is the point of my answer. You retain those things you care about and you don't rely on others to retain them for you. In ObjC, you are not responsible for the things you create. You only have a implicit retain on them (rather than an explicit retain). Reference-counted objects have no owner; no one is "responsible" for their lifecycle as one is responsible with new/delete. All retainers are equal in ObjC.

Comment: I agree that retaining what I care is a good idea, but I don't think I agree with your argument. For example: if I retain the imageview and its superview  gets released I won't get a dangling pointer to my imageview but still I won't be able to use it since it won't be "visible", no touches, etc. In this case retain does not resolve that problem. :( . If I were to receive touches I will simply add GestureRecognizers to the imageview and release it.

Comment: @6NSString: Good question about the downvotes. I've never seen so many on one question. Whoever is doing that, this is too much downvoting.

Comment: @Rob I fundamentally disagree with your understanding of object ownership in Objective C. Ownership rules are clearly described here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH

Comment: @nacho4d It's easy to test if a UIView object is part of a view hierarchy, though. It's harder to test if a pointer points to junk.

Comment: @6NSString What specifically are you objecting to? Other than @Rob not being crystal clear about when you should release an object, everything looks pretty good.

Comment: @nacho4d The point here of retaining isn't to ensure your program works correctly, but to ensure it doesn't crash. If you code it poorly, you'll hold onto memory for longer than you should (not technically a leak, but still, too much memory). But I always encourage programming styles that, even when done sloppily, still won't crash. Then, I encourage people to fix up their code to be more efficient. :D

Comment: @6NSString, I concede that Cocoa uses the word "ownership" in a way different than I'm using it here. As Apple says "any object may have one or more owner." This is very different than what "ownership" means in most other languages, and so when I teach Cocoa, I avoid equating ownership with retain. Specifically, Cocoa "ownership" does not give you any *responsibility* for the object's lifecycle. All retainers are equal. The original question asked not when retains happen, but whether he should have kept a retain. The answer is you retain what you care about, with few exceptions.

Comment: BTW, my (slightly) longer discussion of this topic is here: http://robnapier.net/blog/three-magic-words-6. I don't think anything there should be really controversial (I even use the word "ownership").

Comment: @Rob I see where you're coming from, and your explanation makes sense to me now. I just see it a bit different, probably because I program almost exclusively in Obj-C and have little practice in explaining it to newbies.

Answer (score 1):

As long as your myUIImageView object has a retain count > 0, it will still exist and you can continue using it. When you first add it as a subview, it gets a retain message so it's retain count is likely 2. Then you send it release, so its retain count is reduced to 1. This means it still exists in memory. Now, if you sent it release again, or sent it `removeFromSuperView` then its retain count would be zero, and you'd lose it.

Comment: Ok, this I understand, so when should be a good time to call removeFromSuperView, can you call that in the dealloc?

Comment: +1 to counter the crazy downvote. @molle, you'd almost never call removeFromSuperview in dealloc. You'd only call that to do manual reorganization of the views. @6NSString is giving what ObjC *does*, and he's correct, but I don't believe he's making a suggestion of what *you* should do. You should retain the pieces you care about, and release them when you're done with them. If you add a view to a superview and release it, then its that new superview's problem to hold onto it at long as it needs it.

Comment: I downvoted because the answer doesn't make it clear that you should never send `release` to an object twice or send messages to an object you just released. @6NSString's answer was a theoretical exercise, not anything that you should ever be doing in practice.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior is erratic, sometimes you may see it works, sometimes you get a crash.

If you want to use that variable to point to your image view, retain the ivar (by using a `retain` property). This way you ensure that the image view is available for your controller class to use.

Comment: why the downvotes? This answer is more correct that most of the other answers.

Comment: @kubi: Some rogue downvoter out there I don't know who. Thanks for your response (and I suppose your upvote!) though, I was just about to remove my answer altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming myUIImageView is an ivar of your custom UIView subclass, your code will work as long as your image view stays in his superview. The image view instance may be deallocated and you may end with an invalid pointer referencing a deallocated object. At best you crash.

According to memory management guidelines, you should consider your image view <-> custom uiview subclass relation as wether:

- strong reference. You own the image view (as you created it), and are responsible for retaining / releasing it
- weak reference. You don't own the object, thus keeping a reference to it may be dangerous.

in your case, it's probably a strong reference. your myUIImageView ivar should be a nonatomic retained property of your object.

Answer (score 0):

*If you need to access your `UIImage` at some point in the future, you need to retain it.*

How you do this is at your discretion, but you should *not* rely on the UIView to retrain your objects for you. The situation you've created works for now, but it's fragile.